# Search for mixed formats

Tags: microsoft-word

I can search for `Hello` in Word, and I can specify if I want to search only for special formats, like italic, but I can only specify the format of the complete expression, not parts of it.

Consider the following example:

[image: Winword screenshot]

- I can search for "Hello Adam" and "Hello Caesar", by searching for `Hello <*>` and setting the style to "Normal".
- I can search for the first "Hello Doris" by by searching for `Hello <*>` and setting the style to "Italic".

How can I search for "Hello Berta" and the second "Hello Doris", being a non-italic "Hello" and a second italic word? Is that even possible?

Comment: You would need VBA for this

Comment: That's my least favourite answer when talking about excel... :-(